# Pro Tempore Moderator Nomination Thread

Tags: discussion, moderation

As per the [Moderator Pro Tempore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/) blog post, I went ahead and created a thread to nominate Pro Tempore Moderators on this new site:

This is the basic structure of a Moderator nomination thread:

- The question should be community wiki.
- Each nomination should be a separate answer. Link the name to the user’s profile (parent and meta) so we can see their activity.
- The nominee should indicate their acceptance by editing the answer, adding that they accept the nomination. Optionally they can write something about themselves.
- Self nominations are okay, and even encouraged. Most sites have not had sufficient time for many users to stand out. Self nomination is simply a way to say, “I’m interested. Let my record speak for itself.” Links to other activities may be helpful: Area 51 participation, participation in other sites, blog posts reviewing or announcing the site, etc.
  Include the bullet points (from above) to show what we are looking for.

According to the blog, Pro Tempore Moderators are generally selected 2 weeks after the public beta begins.

If you wish to nominate yourself or another, please read the [blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/) and post 1 nomination per answer.

If interested in nominating oneself as a moderator, it's also a good idea to read [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/), which is the owners manual for every moderator.

Answer (score 1):

[Patrick](https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/users/5/patrick) would be a good choice as a Pro Tempore Moderator.  Here are his credentials:

- High reputation on the main site, indicating regular, active participation. [Patrick - Main Site](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/users/5/patrick)
- Several posts on meta that help define the direction of the site, such as what is on-topic and off-topic. [Patrick - Meta](https://mechanics.meta.stackexchange.com/users/5/patrick)
- Has followed through on at least 2 committments and is committed to other yet-to-be-formed sites as well:  [Patrick - Area51](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/users/28099/patrick)

This user also seems like someone that would read [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/) and do his best to adhere to those principles.